# Formulario phpmailer llega vacío a mi correo

Tags: php

Por favor, si alguien puede orientarme.
Formulario llega vacío a  mi correo.
Muchas gracias.
Este es el enviar.php:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to

$mail->Host = "mail.boris.cl"; // specify main and backup server $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication $mail->Username = 'contacto@boris.cl'; // SMTP username $mail->Password = "di****8?"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "contacto@boris.cl"; $mail->FromName = "remitente"; // remitente $mail->AddAddress("bvr@gmail.com", "destinatario"); // destinatario

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters $mail->IsHTML(true); // set email

$mail->Subject = "Asunto ....."; $mail->Body = "Cuerpo del mensaje";

if(!$mail->Send()) { echo "Error al enviar.

"; echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; exit; }

echo "Mensaje enviado!"; ?>
```

Comment: El correo llega? y si este llega lo hace vacio?

Comment: Luis, sólo llega esto: MENSAJE ENVIADO DESDE TU PÁGINA WEB!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando, SMTP Debugging

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comment: ahora sale "cuerpo del mensaje"

Comment: $mail->Subject = "Asunto .....";
$mail->Body    = "Cuerpo del mensaje";